# Calling a method from another class in java

Tags: java, user-interface, bluej

I am using BlueJ and i am trying to call a method from another class. To be more specific i am trying to complete the following.

When the download music button is pressed, if a suitable value has been entered for the display number:

- The display number is used to get the gadget, cast as MP3, from the array list.
- The method to download music in the MP3 class is called with the
  download size entered.

Here is the gadgetshop class that builds the GUI and the place where i want to call the downloadMusic method. the method for the button is called downloadMusic.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GadgetShop implements ActionListener
{
//Array List 
private ArrayList<Gadget>gadgets;


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{

    if (command.equals("Download Music"))
    {
        downloadMusic();
    }
}  

public void addMp3()
{
    MP3 mp3 = new MP3(getWeight(), getPrice(), getModel(), getSize(), getMemory());
    gadgets.add(mp3);
}

public void displayAll()
{
    for(Gadget gadget : gadgets)
    {
        gadget.print();
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public void downloadMusic()
{
}

public int getDisplay()
{
    int gadgetDisplay = 0;
    try
    {
        gadgetDisplay = Integer.parseInt(displayText.getText());

    if (gadgetDisplay<= 0)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
      (frame, "Please enter a positive amount");  
    }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException exception)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (frame, "Please enter a positive amount");
    }
    return gadgetDisplay;
}

public String getDownload()
{
    String gadgetDownload;
    gadgetDownload = downloadText.getText();
    return gadgetDownload;
}
}
```

This is the MP3 class

```
public class MP3 extends Gadget
{

private int memory;

public MP3(int theWeight, double thePrice, String theModel, String theSize, int theMemory)
{
    super(theWeight,thePrice, theModel, theSize);
    memory = theMemory;
}

public void downloadMusic(String music, int MusicSize)
{
    if(MusicSize>memory)
    //if statement saying if size is greater than memory then display the follwing statemnt saying there is not enough memory
    {
        System.out.println("Not Enough Memory");
    }
    else
    // else statement opposite to the above statement saying if music size is less than or equal to the memory display the following statement
    {
        memory = memory - MusicSize;
        System.out.println("Download Successfull. "+ "\nMusic Name: "+ music + "\nMemory Left: " + memory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim down your code to what is necessary to understand your problem.

Comment: You have pasted a gazillon lines of code but didn't ask a question. What problem do you have?

Comment: Please, please frame these type of questions when you have just 2 classes which comprise only a few lines of code.  People typically won't try to work through so much code.

Comment: sorry about that. i wasn't sure how much information was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"other class"* (with the button) must have an instance of the class with the method you want to call. You could create an instance of `MP3` in the constructor of `GadgetShop` and store it as an instance variable. Then in your button listener call

```
mp3Instance.downloadMusic("music", 42);
```

Comment: the instance has to be confined within the downloadMusic method in gadgetshop. whould it be something along the lines of    MP3 mp3Instance = new MP3();

Comment: @user2290426 There is no downloadMusic class in gadgetshop.

Comment: sorry i meant the downloadMusic method.